# How to get multiple nested keys outside a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, printing

I'm trying to print out some nested keys inside my list. Below is my list.

```
my_list = [
'url',
 100,
 [{'food1': 'sushi',
   'food2': 'tajine',
   'fruit': {'desert': {'sweet': 'tiramusi'}, 'exotic': 'mango'}},
  {'food1': 'rice',
   'food2': 'tajinev',
   'fruit': {'desert': {'sweet': 'ice-cream'}, 'exotic': 'banana'}},
  {'food1': 'tajine',
   'food2': 'burger',
   'fruit': {'desert': {'sweet': 'cheesecake'}, 'exotic': 'pineapple'}}]]
```

**Now my aim is to print the following:**

1. I want all the `exotics fruits`
2. I want all the `sweet inside deserts`

**This is my code:**

```
for x in my_list:
    print(x[2][0]['fruit']['exotic']) #<--- these are the exotic fruits
    print(x[2][0]['desert']['sweet']) #<--- these are the sweet deserts
```

I receive the following error: `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`

**My expected outcome would be:**

```
mango
banana
pineapple
tiramisu
ice-cream
cheesecake
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're iterating the wrong place. Try this:

```
my_list = [
    ('url'), 100, [
        {'food1': 'sushi', 'food2': 'tajine', 
        'fruit': {'exotic': 'mango', 'desert': {'sweet': 'tiramusi'}}}, 
        {'food1': 'rice', 'food2': 'tajinev', 
        'fruit': {'exotic': 'banana', 'desert': {'sweet': 'ice-cream'}}}, 
        {'food1': 'tajine', 'food2': 'burger', 
        'fruit': {'exotic': 'pineapple', 'desert': {'sweet': 'cheesecake'}}}
    ]
]

for x in my_list[2]:
    print(x['fruit']['exotic']) #<--- these are the exotic fruits
    print(x['fruit']['desert']['sweet']) #<--- these are the sweet deserts
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct code

```
# Original List

my_list = [
('url'), 100, 
[{'food1': 'sushi', 'food2': 'tajine', 'fruit': {'exotic': 'mango', 'desert': {'sweet': 'tiramusi'}}}, 
{'food1': 'rice', 'food2': 'tajinev', 'fruit': {'exotic': 'banana', 'desert': {'sweet': 'ice-cream'}}}, 
{'food1': 'tajine', 'food2': 'burger', 'fruit': {'exotic': 'pineapple', 'desert': {'sweet': 'cheesecake'}}}]
]

# Print All Exotic Fruits

for i in range(len(my_list)):
    
    print(my_list[2][i]['fruit']['exotic'])

# Print all Sweets
    
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    
    print(my_list[2][i]['fruit']['desert']['sweet'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use ['fruit']['desert']['sweet'] instead of ['desert']['sweet'].

```
x=[
('url'), 100, [{'food1': 'sushi', 'food2': 'tajine', 
'fruit': {'exotic': 'mango', 'desert': {'sweet': 'tiramusi'}}}, 
{'food1': 'rice', 'food2': 'tajinev', 
'fruit': {'exotic': 'banana', 'desert': {'sweet': 'ice-cream'}}}, 
{'food1': 'tajine', 'food2': 'burger', 
'fruit': {'exotic': 'pineapple', 'desert': {'sweet': 'cheesecake'}}}]
]

print(*(map(lambda x:x['fruit']['exotic'],x[2])),sep="\n")
print(*(map(lambda x:x['fruit']['desert']['sweet'],x[2])),sep="\n")
```